# Applying dynamic mask across all images to make uniform with baseline

Tags: ffmpeg, filter, time-lapse

I do time lapses. In the attached image, notice each image has slightly different shades but are otherwise consistent. This is an artifact of a mechanical shutter.

[image: Collection of slightly off image thumbnails]

I'd like to take a single pixel in the images that will not change color and use this as the baseline. Then apply a mask to the rest of the images in the sequence to make them match the baseline image.

I imagine the code would look something like this:

```
baseline_color = `convert baseline.png -format '#%[hex:u.p{75,20}]' info:-`

for i in images/
do
    #get the color of the same pixel in another image
    new_color = `convert $i -format '#%[hex:u.p{75,20}]' info:-`

    #get the difference betwen the two colors
    diff = baseline_color - new_color

    #apply filter to make image color consistent with baseline
    ffmpeg -i $i -vf "filter=..." $i_filtered.png
done
```

Any thoughts on how to best accomplish this?

Comment: I may end up using [normalization](http://johnriselvato.com/ffmpeg-how-to-add-color-normalization-to-a-video/) instead

Comment: Alternatively, the answer may lie in the curves filter if I can make it work. Then the pseudocode above would apply.

Comment: Another option is the [histmatch](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/histmatch/index.php) ImageMagick script